# Does an AWS Lightsail database instance support multiple databases?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to understand exactly what a "Database" is within Amazon Lightsail. I've attempted to research this as much as possible through Google and various forums, but information on this particular issue seems limited.

My impression (and hope) is that a "Database" as far as Lightsail is concerned is actually a database instance, or in other words a virtual machine running a database server, that once created is able to be used to hold multiple databases.

I tried to test this theory by creating a Database instance on lightsail, then connecting to it using MySQL Workbench, and running a "CREATE test_db" query. From what I could tell, this seemed to work, but it was the first time I'd used Workbench, so was not entirely convinced I'd created a database within my instance.

Can anyone please offer some clarity on this matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Lightsail database instance is a MySQL server running in Amazon RDS.  You have exclusive use of this server -- is isn't shared.  You can create as many databases ("schemas") on it as you want using standard queries.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. I understand it now, and that's been very helpful to me.